# aggregate then update to other collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to insert the returned data of my aggregate (controller function) to another collection called User. Below is my schema for the User:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'First name is required']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Last name is required']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Email is required']
    },
    loginType: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Login type is required']
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    transactions: [{transactionId: String}, date:{type:Date, default:new Date()}],
    totalIncome : [{id:String},{totalIncome:Number}]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I want to insert the result of this controller function into User collection as another variable

```
return Transaction.aggregate([ { $match : { userId : userId, type:"Income",isActive:true} }, {
            $group: {
                _id: "$type",
                totalIncome: {
                $sum: "$amount"
                 }
                }
    }
    ]).then((totalIncome,err)=> {
        return (err) ? false : totalIncome
    })
```

The result of my aggregate above is this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "Income",
        "totalIncome": 18000
    }
]
```

Please help :( I tried adding `$out` but it replaces the whole user collection.

I just want it to add to a specific user and update its content every time I use the controller function above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
return Transaction.aggregate([ { $match : { userId : userId, type:"Income",isActive:true} }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$type",
            amount: {
            $sum: "$amount"
             }
            }
            
} 
]).then((totalIncome,err)=> {
    // return (err) ? false : totalIncome
    console.log(totalIncome)
    if (err) {
        return false
    } else {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {"$set" : {"totalIncome": totalIncome[0].amount }}, { "new": true })
        .then((transaction, err ) => {
            return (err) ? false : true
        })
    }
})
```

I was able to add totalIncome to my User collection by using findByIdAndUpdate() and $set operator. Feel free to provide different solution for my question above.